# Do shared libraries reduce memory footprint on WebSphere AppServer 7?

Tags: memory, websphere, libraries, shared, footprint

I've created 1 shared library for several wars on WebSphere AppServer 7. "Use an isolated class loader for this shared library" is not checked. Does it reduce the memory consumption compared to the situation where the library is located in the WEB-INF\lib directory of WAR file?

Answer (score 1):

Isolated shared libraries are designed to:

- save memory footprint, avoid loading the same class multiple times
- allow a set of applications exclusively share a copy of shared library
- allow version handling with the minimum number of library copies loaded

Source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/Administration/WASv7_IsolatedSharedLibraries/player.html

So both shared library and isolated shared library **should** reduce memory footprint significantly.

The effect is increased by the fact of memory leak on redeploy. Less libraries to redeploy reduces the memory leaks too.